# Multiple config files for flyway

Tags: postgresql, flyway

How do we keep multiple config files under the config folder for flyway? When I try to copy and name the config file as postgres, it didn't allow me to save it there.

Answer (score 1):

By default Flyway will only load the `flyway.conf` configuration from the `conf` folder. If you want to have more config files with different names then you need to manually tell Flyway to load them.

e.g. `flyway -configFiles=path/to/myAlternativeConfig.conf migrate`

Read more about this and see more examples https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/commandline/#config-files